# single nouns follow "their"

Tags: grammar

I've seen sentences like:

"A lot of people use their computer to ..."

is it just a typo of "their computers",  or it's correct usage?

Thanks

Comment: See: [singular they](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/they#they__7)

Answer (score 1):

It's very widely used, in BrE at least, and readily understood.  If those two points (widespread usage, comprehensibility) don't make it 'correct' what would ?